# how to access the passthrough video option in android vr

Tags: android, virtual-reality

I am creating a customized android vr app and I want to add the option to integrate a passthrough option using the phone backside camera. Can anyone give me a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

JS:
I would suggest interrogating T.Samshuijzen's Solar System google experiment code. view-source:https://torrid-fire-7484.firebaseapp.com/ the business section mostly happens from line 888.

I had a similar problem and have found support to be patchy: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream